# How do I transpose the movements of an iclone 8 character into a 2D image of a person?

Tags: animation

I am not a designer or animator, and just need this one functionality from iclone. I have a 2D image (jpeg, png) of a character I built in Midjourney, and I know how to add simple body movements to a pre-existing iclone 8 character (for example, Party_F_0001 -> Perform -> Idle01_F). I've added speech to the iclone 8 character by providing a text input in Animation -> Create Script -> Acculips.

Now, how do I superimpose the movements of the Party_F_0001 character into my JPEG character? I know (and have used before) Livelink to transfer the iclone character's movements into a metahuman character in Unreal Engine using Live Link. Is there something similar for transferring animations into 2D image characters? I am also open to converting the 2D image into a 3D object first, if needed (using deep learning models for example), but all methods I've tried so far don't produce high quality results.

Or, the other way round also works. Essentially, all I need is to add simple hand movements and slight body movements as my 2D avatar speaks. I can make the avatar speak with a deep learning model, but don't know how to add the subtle body movements to make it look realistic. If there's a way to add that in my 2D image character using iclone, that's all I need.